# HTML JS form to div comments (temporary change)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have seen many similar problems but when I try them they end up failing. It has gotten to the point where my code is totally messed up and I need some help both cleaning it up and fixing my issue. (using chrome)

So far I have tried selecting the value of the form and putting that into a div,
I have tried to use the button as just a link to start the script so that the page doesn't reset and also many other answers found on-line, none of them are helping so I am asking for a personalised help.

```js
function on_comment_add() {
 
 var main = document.getElementById("div1");
 var add_user_name = document.createElement("div");
 var add_user_comment = document.createElement("div");
 
 add_user_name.setAttribute("id", "add_user_name");
 add_user_comment.setAttribute("id", "add_user_comment");
 
 <!-- var node = document.createTextNode("This is new."); -->
 var node_1 = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
 var node_2 = document.getElementById("user_comment").value;
 
 add_user_name.appendChild(node_1);
 add_user_comment.appendChild(node_2);
 
 var element = document.createElement("div");
 element.setAttribute("id", "display_comment_div");
 element.appendChild(add_user_name);
 element.appendChild(add_user_comment);
 main.appendChild(element);
 main.innerHTML = element;
 
 return false;
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: lightGreen;
}

div.middle {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 background-color: #47e077;
 height: 940px;
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: aubrey;
 border: 3px solid gold;
}

.comments-form {
 text-align: center;
}

#display_comment_div {
 background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.1);
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 9%;
 border: 0.1px solid lightGreen;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

#add_user_name {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
}

#add_user_comment {
 width: 45%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
 <div class="comments-form">
  <form>
   <label for="name" style="width:100px; display:inline-block;">Name</label>
   <input id="user_name" type="text" placeholder="name goes here" style="width:300px; margin-left:5px;" />
   <br><br>
   <label for="comment" style="width:100px; display:inline-block;">Comment</label>
   <textarea id="user_comment" placeholder="comment goes here" maxlength="150" style="width:300px;max-width:300px;"></textarea><br>
   <button style="margin-left:310px;" onmousedown="return on_comment_add">Submit</button>
   
  </form>
  <div id="div1">
  </div>

  
 </div>
</div>
```

I guess what I am asking is if anyone can help me display the username and comment below the form but it seems tricky for me because I have gone through so many answers that don't work for me that I cannot think of any other ways to do it.

**For clarification this code is not meant to keep the comments from the form nor is it meant to be a fully functioning site. I am just making slight modifications to some code so that I can hand it in as  a college assignment.**

Comment: I've up voted (to remove the down vote) as the question appears to meet [What questions can I ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines, i.e., "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using onclick and pass the event inside:

```
<button style="margin-left:310px;" onclick="on_comment_add(event)">Submit</button>
```

And disable the default form submit action:

```
function on_comment_add(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var main = document.getElementById("div1");
    var add_user_name = document.createElement("div");
    var add_user_comment = document.createElement("div");

    add_user_name.setAttribute("id", "add_user_name");
    add_user_comment.setAttribute("id", "add_user_comment");

    var node_1 = document.createElement("div");
  node_1.innerHTML= document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    var node_2 = document.createElement("div");
  node_2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("user_comment").value;

    add_user_name.appendChild(node_1);
    add_user_comment.appendChild(node_2);

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "display_comment_div");
    element.appendChild(add_user_name);
    element.appendChild(add_user_comment);
    main.appendChild(element);

    return false;
}
```

Workable example: https://jsfiddle.net/kingychiu/z6gnqswn/

Answer (score 0):

Change type to "button" to prevent automatical form sending and add parentheses to onmousedown expression:

```
<button type="button" style="margin-left:310px;" onmousedown="return on_comment_add()">Submit</button>
```

Then change this

```
add_user_name.appendChild(node_1);
add_user_comment.appendChild(node_2);
```

to this (since node_1, node_2 are values, not elements):

```
add_user_name.innerHTML = node_1;
add_user_comment.innerHTML = node_2;
```

And remove that line

```
main.innerHTML = element;
```

above

```
return false;
```

That should work.